# Preventing SQL injection by replacing place holders instead of appending user data in query

Tags: java, sql, sql-injection

This may sound a very strange and vague question indeed. 
The mini project I'm working on generates where condition in the query as a complete string, which is then appended to the main query like below:

```
String whereCondition ="someCondition";
String query = "select * from myTable "+ whereCondition;
```

Now, after going through what SQL injection is, I understand this approach is a very bad one and invites SQL injection.
What I wanted to ask is, if I take another approach like mentioned below, will it help in preventing the injection ?

```
String myTable = "table1";
String query =" select * from {0} {1}";
query = query.replace("{0}",myTable).repalce("{1}",whereCondition);
```

Herein, instead of appending the user data and conditions, I'm replacing the placeholders in my query template as per requirement.

It may be yet another bad approach but I need to understand whether it'll work.

Comments and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Some time ago, like 15 years or (probaby) more, somebody came with idea of `PreparedStatements`

Comment: are you using native JDBC if yes you can use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to prevent SQL Injection

Comment: @Antoniossss Table name cannot be parametrized

Comment: @LukaszSzozda the table names the columns.. should be defined statically, should already exist in the code No?

Comment: @YCF_L : Thanks for your comment. Yes, I can use JDBC but problem is that the where condition is dynamically generated and stored in whereCondition variable. i.e. I do not know the columns involved beforehand. That is why I'm not able to use JDBC statements.
You can consider it like table name and whereCondition are being passed to a method and are not static.

Comment: @YCF_L Yes, they should . Here we have  two cases: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Dyn_table and http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Condition

Comment: @YCF_L : If I'm using the above approach, will that help in preventing SQL injection or is it just similar to appending ?

Comment: @IshanAg24 column and table names is not working with Prepared Statement, but values yes, you can prevent any SQL Injection

Comment: @YCF_L : I'm asking about the approach I mentioned actually. i.e. replacing instead of appending. Like I said, I'm not able to use Prepared Statement because I do not know the columns involved beforehand. That's why I'm going with the replacement thing. WIll it work ?

Comment: @IshanAg24 This feels like an X Y problem (https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What are you trying to write that requires generating column names dynamically?

Comment: @IshanAg24 no it is not secure I can attack you easily check this demo https://ideone.com/dVZASk

Comment: The short answer would be that there is absolutely no difference between this approach and just appending. As long as you don't make sure that the condition does not include anything malicious, the way you create the string doesn't matter. The question is if you can generate the condition in a way that ensures that it is sanitized. For this we need to know more about your project, the kind of conditions etc.

Comment: *Scrubbing* the outside-supplied parts of the query, by removing quotes and semicolons (and a few other special characters) is the general approach to prevent injection. This is done to prevent the outside parts from 'escaping' out and inserting additional malicious clauses into the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to SQL injection, string replacement is the same as string concatenation: **UNSAFE.**

How you produce the string is irrelevant. The risk of SQL injection is that you combine unsafe content with the SQL string before you send that string to the database and its SQL parser. The risk is that the unsafe content can influence the logic of the query, by changing the query syntax.

Most of the time, the recommended way to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities is to use query parameters for dynamic content. But query parameters can be used only in place of scalar values in SQL expressions — not table names, column names, whole query clauses, etc.

In your case, you must make sure that the content is safe. A common way to do this is to compare the content to known safe patterns. For example, your string `myTable` should be validated that it matches one of the known tables in your database.

Validating a whole clause like `whereCondition` is more complex. If you produce your `whereCondition` using any content from outside your app (including but not limited to user input, content read from a file, content returned by a web service, content read from the database), then your app is vulnerable.